# How to check if message has been delivered earlier in rabbitMq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, queue

I have a rabitmq server running which has a queue. I publish some data in queue. Now if there is some error processing that message at that time then i reject it as `ch.reject(msg,true)`. So message is consumed again it is again error then again reject it & message will be consumed again. Now i want to know it that message has already been sent because i rejected it.

```
const queueresponse = await self.filterData(JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()));
                            if (queueresponse) {
                                ch.ack(msg);
                                console.log("queue received true")
                            } else {
                                ch.reject(msg, true);
                                console.log("queue received false")
                            }
```

Is there any way to know if consumed messaged has already sent earlier because it was rejected?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Rabbitmq to see if the message was previously rejected.
However, instead of rejecting the message, you can requeue it with some extra data in JSON like

```
{retry_count = 1}
```

When you receive such message next time, you can read it and know that it was requeued previously.

Comment: I tried but there is no such way to append data in current message. I tried but it always return the previous message.

Comment: You have  to ack the current message and publish new message.